# Geth, BSC full node sync "State sync in progress" stuck at 70%

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, nodes, bsc, full-node

I am doing a BSC full node sync using the following command:

```
/mnt/raid/bscdata/geth --syncmode full  --config /mnt/raid/bscdata/config.toml --datadir /mnt/raid/bscdata/node --cache 32000 --rpc.allow-unprotected-txs --txlookuplimit 0
```

The sync process stopped `importing new block headers` at `~26.000.000 block` and started a new process called `"State sync in progress"`. From my understanding, a full sync will import the blocks first and then process those blocks after, from the internet I found that this process starts near the end of import process so in my case it started at `26m block`. So this is ok.

The problem though is that it shows `eta=191h43m49.052s` which is huge, and I found that people manage to process it just a few hours.

Server hardware:

```
CPU:
Architecture:            x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:         46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                  32
  On-line CPU(s) list:   0-31
Vendor ID:               GenuineIntel
  Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2665 0 @ 2.40GHz
    CPU family:          6
    Model:               45
    Thread(s) per core:  2
    Core(s) per socket:  8
    Socket(s):           2
    Stepping:            7
    CPU max MHz:         3100.0000
    CPU min MHz:         1200.0000
    BogoMIPS:            4788.11
RAM: 64GB
STORAGE: 2 x 2T nvme software raid ~3.6T
```

LOG

```
t=2023-04-10T10:03:59+0000 lvl=info msg="State sync in progress"                 synced=0.07% state="403.58 MiB" accounts=1,165,860@26.88MiB slots=1,578,423@339.17MiB codes=5895@37.53MiB eta=191h43m49.052s
```

Also, my cpu is at 3% chilling

How can I speed up the process? should I run `geth` without `--syncmode full`?

UPDATE, will see how it runs
increasing cache to `--cache 48000`, and adding `--gcmode full`

After 1 day it managed to do some progress

```
t=2023-04-12T08:50:22+0000 lvl=info msg="State sync in progress"                 synced=74.82% state="408.35 GiB"  accounts=164,259,736@27.21GiB slots=1,841,074,401@368.40GiB codes=1,611,471@12.74GiB eta=14h52m37.265s
```

But it stopped here for `12h`, and now it's just importing new blocks. cpu is at 0%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I was connected to bad peers. I solved it by updating static peers and restarting geth service.

peers can be found here https://api.binance.org/v1/discovery/peers

also updated geth to the latest version

https://github.com/bnb-chain/bsc/releases/download/v1.1.22/

Answer (score 1):

There is some stuff you can try, the easier one would be to use your node with  `--syncmode fast` option instead of `--syncmode full` it will allow you to download only the recent state of the chain, you can also check that you have a sufficient number of peers `--maxpeers 100`, and also check your network connection.

Increase the cache might help but in any case the ETA you see may not be entirely accurate, as it can fluctuate during the syncing process.

Comment: `invalid value "fast" for flag -syncmode: unknown sync mode "fast", want "full", "snap" or "light"` will try increasing max peers. it was 50

Comment: you could try with -light or -snap